# Wrapping the call Context.getString with formatting arguments results in a IllegalFormatConversionException

Tags: java, android, string, kotlin, text-formatting

I am trying to create a wrapper for the `Context#getString(id, args)` method so I write less code:

```kotlin
fun Context.string(@StringRes strId: Int, vararg fmtArgs: Any?) = getString(strId, fmtArgs)
```

When calling the function results in the following stack-trace:

```
2020-04-17 13:26:20.778 24143-24143/mypackage E/ERROR:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:267)
            ... 45 more
     Caused by: java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != [Ljava.lang.Object;
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4403)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2885)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2839)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2524)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2459)
        at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2911)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:485)
        at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:655)
        at mypackage.ktx.ContextKt.string(Context.kt:28)
```

Seen the issue, I took a look at `kotlin.text` to see how they perform String formatting with arguments...

```kotlin
/**
 * Uses this string as a format string and returns a string obtained by substituting the specified arguments,
 * using the default locale.
 */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun String.format(vararg args: Any?): String = java.lang.String.format(this, *args)
```

I adapted to the new call-style

```kotlin
fun Context.string(@StringRes strId: Int, vararg fmtArgs: Any?) = getString(strId, *fmtArgs)
```

…and still, it crashes with the same stack trace.

I decided to get just the String and then manually format it by using JetBrains implementation and see if there were some internals that I didn't think about:

```kotlin
fun Context.string(@StringRes strId: Int, vararg fmtArgs: Any?) = getString(strId).format(fmtArgs)
```

I see the issue is that the `%d` doesn't correspond to an object, but if Android can manage to have this working and kotlin format aswell with alike calls…

What's the solution in this case?

Comment: are you trying to override this method just so you can write 3 characters less?

Comment: I am not overriding, I am wrapping. And yes, it looks way cleaner in a DSL to write string(id) than getString(id)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I adapted to the new call-style
>
> `fun Context.string(@StringRes strId: Int, vararg fmtArgs: Any?) = getString(strId, *fmtArgs)`

This works. After inlining and de-inlining the gradle build-cache refreshed and this started working.

Comment: doesn't work for me, what do you mean by inlining and de-inlining the gradle build-cache?

Comment: While trying random stuff the gradle build cache refreshed (what I tried was to make an inline function, compile it and no-longer make it an inline function and re-compile it) and started accepting this call style. I've got a personal lib and two whole projects using this function so you just need to make gradle obey your orders :)!

Answer (score 0):

First and last examples pass the array as first parameter because the `*` spread operator is missing and the compiler is fine with it because `vararg fmtArgs: Any?` is a `Array<Any?>`, but also a `Any`.
`getString(strId, *fmtArgs)` should have worked though.